# xdebug breaks on collecting... using phalcon

Tags: php, crash, xampp, xdebug, phalcon

I'm using windows 7, x86, PhpStorm 6 on Xampp 1.8. When using classes with 

`\Phalcon\Mvc\Model`
 
like this:

`class MyClass extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model

    {

    ...

    }`

My Xdebug will no be able to collect any object information. I found a related [issue](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/598) but its not the same problem.

Comment: You might want to upgrade to the latest XDebug. That solved the similar issue for many people.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with XDebug — you will need at least 2.2.3 if you run ZTS-enabled PHP.

This is [the commit](https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/commit/489d483d029e3cbfa9eaed0407f4ece020825360) that fixed the issue in XDebug.